# How to sort files in assets folder?

Tags: java, android, string, sorting, assets

Here are faced with the problem of sorting files. Choose the files from the folder Asset. How to sort files in ascending?
Here is my code:

```
//fillGrid
private void fillGridAdapter(int cat) {
   ASSETS_IMAGE_DIR = imagePath[cat];
   addImages(getImages(imagePath[cat]));
}
//Adds the files
private void addImages(String[] temp){
   imBitmap = new Bitmap[temp.length];
   if(temp != null) {
   for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
       try {
    imBitmap[i] = getBitmapFromAsset(imagePath[g.getImageCat()]+"/"+temp[i]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
      }
    }
}
private String[] getImages(String f){
        try {
        AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
        String[] temp = assetManager.list(f);

        Arrays.sort(temp);
        return temp;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

After assetManager.list(f) String[] temp - (1.jpg, 10.jpg, 12.jpg ... 9.jpg). After Arrays.sort(temp) - (1.jpg, 10.jpg, 12.jpg ... 9.jpg). And I need to - 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg... n.jpg.

Comment: is number of image in asset folder is fixed?

Comment: add all image names to arraylist and use collection to sort

Answer (score 0):

Use [Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Here's an example http://www.coderanch.com/t/378718/java/java/sort-array-files-directories

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to sort the files into numeric order ... not lexical order.

To achieve this, you will need to split the pathnames into a numeric and non-numeric segments.  For the numeric segment(s) you need to parse the segment as an integer and sort based on the integer values.

It looks like your files are of the form `<number>.<suffix>`, so the splitting should be simple.

This logic needs to be implemented in the `compare` method of a `Comparator` which you provides a parameter to `sort`.